# Why aren't any of collections being defined after publishing them?

Tags: javascript, meteor, import, export, publish-subscribe

I keep on getting these error messages in my browser console:

```
Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: "CollectionNames" is not defined
```

The "CollectionNames" being all the collections I have in my app. I have researched but cant find a suitable solution.

My environment: 
I am running meteor 1.2

The task.js file is where I define each collection. Below is the code in task.js 
/myMeteorApp 
--/imports/api/tasks.js

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})] });

buyList = new Mongo.Collection("BuyList");

WhoAreWe = new Mongo.Collection("whoDb");
merchantReviews = new Mongo.Collection("merchantReviews");

Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages", {transform: function (doc) 
{ doc.buyListObj = buyList.find({sessionIDz: {$in: [doc.buyList]}});  return doc; }});
```

The server is where I publish the collections. Below is the code: 
/myMeteorApp 
--/server/main.js

```
import buyList from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
import Messages from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
import Images from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
import WhoAreWe from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
import merchantReviews from '../imports/api/tasks.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
// code to run on server at startup

Meteor.publish('buyList', function(){
return buyList.find();
});


Meteor.publish('Messages', function(){
return Messages.find();
});

Meteor.publish('Images', function(){
return Messages.find();
});


Meteor.publish('WhoAreWe', function(){
return WhoAreWe.find();
});

Meteor.publish('merchantReviews', function(){
return merchantReviews.find();
});

});
```

And the client is where I subscribe for the collections. Find below the code:

/myMeteorApp 
--/client/main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import './main.html';

Meteor.subscribe('Messages');
Meteor.subscribe('WhoAreWe');
Meteor.subscribe('Images');
Meteor.subscribe('buyList');
```

Where am I going wrong. I've been at this for many days now... Kindly help!

Comment: You say: "The "CollectionNames" being all the collections I have in my app. I have researched but cant find a suitable solution." - but it doesn't appear in the code you provided - does it appear somewhere else?

Comment: If you are still using the same structure from your other question, then your import (and export) statements are wrong. Take a look at [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: @Mikkel Sorry about not being transparent enough. The error message appears in the browser Console: `Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Messages is not defined`, &  `Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: buyList is not defined` & `Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: WhoAreWe is not defined` Furthermore in the terminal I also see this error message: `Exception from sub Messages id HSFGnGG4eNrpG3Mo7 TypeError: Messages.find is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collections must be *defined* on both the client and the server! Just import your collection names on the client side as well as the server:

```
import { buyList, Messages, Images, WhoAreWe, merchantReviews } from '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

You still have to *subscribe* to the various *publications* of course.

Answer (score 0):

It is a naming problem, when you publish the collection, you should refer to the collection name (messages), not the meteor variable (Messages)

```
Meteor.publish('messages', function(){...
```